# C# Как создать и передать IDispatch в COM DLL

Tags: c#

На C# надо подключить DLL работающую по COM технологии.

Подключение COM-DLL и вызов из нее функций я написал - документации море.
Но вот в одной функции DLL требует чтобы ей в качестве параметра передали указатель на IDispatch.
B в этом указателе на IDispatch было реализовано два стандартых COM интерфейса : IMsgBox и IPlatformInfo

На C# такое можно сделать? 
Если да то можно которенький примерчик?

**Обновление**

Не подскажите: нужные мне интерфейсы унаследованы от `IUnknown`. Мне надо тоже реализовывать интерфейс `IUnknown` с его функциям (`QueryInterface`, `AddRef`...)?

Получить мне надо вот такой интерфейс:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("55272A00-42CB-11CE-8135-00AA004BB851")
IPropertyBag : public IUnknown {
public:
   virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Read( 
      /* [in] */ LPCOLESTR pszPropName,
      /* [out][in] */ VARIANT *pVar,
      /* [unique][in] */ IErrorLog *pErrorLog) = 0;

   virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Write( 
      /* [in] */ __RPC__in LPCOLESTR pszPropName,
      /* [in] */ __RPC__in VARIANT *pVar) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Первое. Добавьте в ваш проект ссылку на COM-библиотеку типов в студии, либо другим образом получите интерфейсы IMsgBox и IPlatformInfo.

Второе. Реализуйте эти интерфейсы в некотором классе. Оформлять этот класс специальным образом не нужно:

```
class MyClass : IMsgBox, IPlatformInfo {
  // ...
}
```

Третье.  Импортируйте функцию из DLL через P/Invoke, указав [MarshallAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)([IDispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
[DllImport("bar")]
static extern void Foo([MarshallAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object obj)
```

---

По поводу обновления. Нет, вам не надо реализовывать IUnknown самостоятельно, так же как и IDispatch. Эти интерфейсы будут реализованы средой.

Comment: А передавать в obj - что? MyClass?
Но тогда компилятор справедливо ругается: 
"Заданное приведение является недопустимым."

Comment: А передавать в obj - что? MyClass?
Но тогда компилятор справедливо ругается: 
"Заданное приведение является недопустимым."

Comment: @ДмитрийГарбуз не верю. Проверьте еще раз все ли вы правильно сделали.

Comment: Заработало только после того как пометил класс атрибутами:
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]

Comment: @ДмитрийГарбуз э... Если класс реализует нужные интерфейсы - это не обязательно.

Comment: @ДмитрийГарбуз в любом случае, компилятор никак не мог ругаться на отсутствие этих атрибутов